# How to know when MKPinAnnotationView pin callout opens/closes

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I want to update pin callout (popup) subtitle either realtime, when I receive some new info from server, or at least when callout opens. So far it looks like pin + callout are created only once at...

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView 
        viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

...and then used as-is as long as it exists regardless how many times I tap it closed/open or scroll around keeping it visible. **How can I update the subtitle?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer completely beacuse I've never needed to do it but [this bit of documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW23) looks like a pointer in the right direction.

Try just updating the `subititle` property of your `<MKAnnotation>` object when a new response comes in from the server and the MapView should update itself?

If not, try removing and re-adding the annotation when the info changes?

Comment: Pins are for search results, so there's a lot of them. Update from server just gives some real-time info for those results. Don't know (yet) how to identify one from another... but that tip about KVO looks promising!

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to store which MKAnnotation belongs to which results from the server - some sort of NSDictionary perhaps? Let me know how you get on - I'm really interested in how you solve this!

Comment: Thanx, you set me to right direction :) Not completely solved yet, but works somehow, when I always update subtitle at viewForAnnotation. This sample code was helpful http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

edit:: There's a much better solution using key-value observing, which includes adding an observer to the `selected` property of the `MKAnnotationView`, then dealing with it appropriately in the callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
```

You can view the solution here: http://blog.evandavey.com/2009/07/how-to-detect-when-mkannotation-mkannotationview-is-selected.html

---

(old solution)

I had a similar problem. It looks like you've gotten most of it. In your function:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView 
    viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

Just make sure to add a callback (aka. selector) to each annotation. For me, I actually want a `UIButton` for them to click on, so I created one and added it as the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` for the annotation.

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

I then created a function called `showDetails` in whatever delegate you passed to the `addTarget` variable (in my case self, which is a custom `UIViewController`).

Now, whenever anyone clicks on any annotation, the `showDetails` function gets called.

However, I'm having problems with figuring out which specific annotation gets called, as I have many on my map, and the caller of the `showDetails` function is not the annotation, but the specific `UIButton`.

I've looked into this solution: [Clean solution to know which MKAnnotation has been tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329654/clean-solution-to-know-which-mkannotation-has-been-tapped), but it only deals with the event inside `viewForAnnotation`, which, as you mentioned, only gets called at the creation of each annotation, and not when they get tapped.